# Solve in integers $b^{11}-1=a^{2016}+a^{2015}+\dots+1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all integers $(a,b)$ satisfying $$b^{11}-1=a^{2016}+a^{2015}+\dots+1.$$

Obviously, we can get the factorisation $(b-1)(b^{10}+\dots+1)=a^{2016}+a^{2015}+\dots+1$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: I thought $(b^{11} - 1)(a-1) = a^{2017} - 1$ looked more like the "obvious" thing to do. I still don't know if it helps, though.

Comment: Note that the equation given by arthur is only equivalent to the given one, if $a\ne 1$. But that does not really matter because $a=1$ does not lead to a solution anyway.

Comment: Note that the only primes that divide the right side are primes of the form $2017k+1$ or $2017$. The only primes that divide the left side are primes of the form $11\ell+1$, or $11$ or primes that divide $b-1$

Comment: It would help to know the source of this problem - if it is an exercise from a book or contest, we can be fairly certain it is solvable without years of research. If it was something you just made up off the top of your head, it might not be tractable.

Comment: yes, this is from a test, so most likely it is solveable.

Comment: It would be easy to solve if the right side ended at $2013$ rather than $2016$. :)

Comment: Since 2017 is prime, Fermat's Little Theorem might be involved?

Comment: No solutions below $a=10^4$.

Comment: I think I proved no such $a$ exists, but calculations were very complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a^{2016}+a^{2015}+\dots+a+1$ has only prime factors that are $0,1$ modulo $2017$.

This implies that $b^{11} \equiv 1,2 \pmod {2017}$.

Therefore, $b^{2013} \equiv 1,2^{183} \pmod {2017}$ or $b^3,2^{183}b^3 \equiv 1 \pmod {2017}$.

This implies that $b \equiv 1 \pmod {2017}$ or $b^2+b+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {2017}$ or $2^{61}b \equiv 1 \pmod {2017}$ or $2^{122}b^2+2^{61}b+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {2017}$.

Since $b^{10}+b^9+\dots+b+1 \equiv 0,1 \pmod {2017}$, it is not difficult to see that $b \not \equiv 1 \pmod {2017}$ and $b^2+b+1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod {2017}$.

Also, note that if $2^{61}b \equiv 1 \pmod {2017}$ or $2^{122}b^2+2^{61}b+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {2017}$, $b-1 \not \equiv 1,0 \pmod {2017}$. Therefore, no such solutions exist.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence.

Comment: @Lucian It is a result of a property of Cyclotomic polynomials. See Thomas Andrews comment.